# PHP & MySQL: Count number of similar rows with one row same, in one statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with columns: `userid`, `productid`

I want to do the following in one statement:
For each member count the number of productids that match the productids for another specified member.

Example table:

```
userid productid
1      10
1      14
2      10
3      12
3      14
3      10
3      19
4      15
```

In the above example, if I specified userid 1 then I want to get a result that looks like:

```
userid matches
2      1
3      2
4      0
```

The result would look like the above because these are the productids from each user that match the productids from my specified user (1).

In reality I would also want to order it by `matches desc` and only where `matches>0`. So it would be:

```
userid matches
3      2
2      1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) See [about Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: @JohnConde, well... SQL statements either work or they don't work. So far I have been unable to make it do what I want. I don't think it would be helpful to list here many incorrect SQL statements.

Comment: If they don't work we can tell you what you;re doing wrong. If you don't show us anything, we're just doing your work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.UserID, COUNT(*) `matches`
FROM    TableName a
        INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT  ProductID
            FROM    TableName
            WHERE   userID = 1
        ) b ON a.ProductID = b.ProductID
WHERE   a.userID <> 1
GROUP   BY a.UserID
HAVING  COUNT(*) > 0
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2ec3c/2)

THE OUTPUT

```
╔════════╦═════════╗
║ USERID ║ MATCHES ║
╠════════╬═════════╣
║      2 ║       1 ║
║      3 ║       2 ║
╚════════╩═════════╝
```